# How to gather CPU and RAM information using Powershell and display into one table

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script that gather the CPU and RAM information from the Local computer, but I need it to display in the same row.

```
 $installed = 
    $processor = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor | Select-Object -Property Name
    $memory = Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory  | Format-Table BankLabel, Capacity, Manufacturer
    $result = $processor, $memory
    
    
    $result | out-file test.txt
```

What I got

```
SystemName Name                                    
---------- ----                                    
EX    Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8500T CPU @ 2.10GHz



  Capacity Manufacturer
  -------- ------------
8589934592 80AD000080AD
```

What I want to achieve

```
SystemName Name                                 Capacity Manufacturer                          
---------- ----                                 ---------------------                          
EX    Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8500T CPU @ 2.10GHz
```

Are there any ways to emerge the two tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Create a custom PowerShell object.

```
# Gather the data from the local (or remote) system
$processor = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor
$memory = Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory

# Create a custom PowerShell object with the desired properties
[PSCustomObject]@{
  SystemName = $processor.SystemName
  Name = $processor.Name
  MemoryCapacity = $memory.Capacity
  Manufacturer = $memory.Manufacturer
}
```

Here's what the output looks like on my system.

```
SystemName Name                                            MemoryCapacity             Manufacturer
---------- ----                                            --------------             ------------
ARTEMIS    AMD Ryzen 9 3900X 12-Core Processor             {17179869184, 17179869184} {Unknown, Unknown}
```

Comment: Thanks! got it!

Comment: Happy to help! @jinxinbo

Comment: May I add, if you're not limited to Powershell 1/2.0.  I recommend using the newer `Get-CimInstance` cmdlets introduced in Powershell 3.0.